# Time series forecasting

Tags: r, time-series

I create time series model via:

```
model = sarima(data,1,0,1)
sarima.for(data,100,1,0,1)
```

The model diagnostics look good and indicate that the model is a good fit. However, when I try to forecast the data, all the forecasted values are the same. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The data series looks more-or-less stationary. You wouldn't expect the forecasted conditional mean of a stationary time series to change over time. However, if you were to simulate this process, then you could generate a distribution of forecasted values in each period.

Comment: Is there a way I could do this? Also, this is the differenced data so the original data is not stationary. Is there a way I can forecast on the original data?

Comment: you don't need to difference data for a sarima model.  the i in sarima model is for integrated and handles differencing the data. use the original data to build the sarima model.